# PrimeFaces PolarArea Chart - GridLine Color Change

Tags: javascript, charts, primefaces, chart.js, jqplot

I have a `p:polarAreaChart` chart in my application and I use *Primefaces primefaces-7.0.RC1 with JSF2*.

I want to change the line color of each circle (GridLine). I have tried the following code but didn't work at all.

```
gridLines.setDisplay(true);

gridLines.setColor("rgb(255, 255, 255)");

gridLines.setLineWidth(10);

radialScales.setGridLines(gridLines);

options.setScales(radialScales);

polarAreaMode.setOptions(options);
```

Please let me know what I have done wrong here?

Comment: Please add error/actual output vs. expected output.

Comment: I didn't get any error. Expected output is "Grid line should be changed to the color that I mentioned" but nothing was happening.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do it easily.  See this example: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/polar-area.html

and in the view source of that page using "backgroundColor":

```
        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

        var chartColors = window.chartColors;
        var color = Chart.helpers.color;
        var config = {
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        color(chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                        color(chartColors.orange).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                        color(chartColors.yellow).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                        color(chartColors.green).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                        color(chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                    ],
                    label: 'My dataset' // for legend
                }],
                labels: [
                    'Red',
                    'Orange',
                    'Yellow',
                    'Green',
                    'Blue'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Polar Area Chart'
                },
                scale: {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    reverse: false
                },
                animation: {
                    animateRotate: false,
                    animateScale: true
                }
            }
        };
```

And looking in the PrimeFaces Source code for PolarAreaChart I see BackgroundColor takes a List of Strings which are the RGB string.

```java
public class PolarAreaChartDataSet extends ChartDataSet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Number> data;
    private List<String> backgroundColor;
    private List<String> borderColor;
    private List<Number> borderWidth;
    private List<String> hoverBackgroundColor;
    private List<String> hoverBorderColor;
    private List<Number> hoverBorderWidth;
```